# Is there way to save the save state?

Tags: nintendo, game-boy-advance

I found my Game Boy Advance in a box a few days ago, and I'm already playing good old Mario games. The problem is that I usually don't have time to finish the whole level at the same time (or I might want to savescum).

Is there way to save (and load) the game state somehow, by using external parts?

Comment: Also welcome retrocomputing!

Comment: How does my [suggested edit](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/394) "deviates from the original intent of the post?"

Comment: @JAL you removed the last part of "or not". I meant through rom editing etc when I wrote "not", so you changed a big part of the question when you removed that. I'll accept your edit if you leave out that part.

Comment: The "or not" is cruft and implied.

Comment: @JAL you are kinda correct, I don't think that this question will be read much more too, so yeah, sorry for not accepting your edit, send it again.

Answer (score 5):

I would say no. I've never heard of anything like that ever. That would require dumping all of the memory of the actual Gameboy and the state of CPU, and then reading that information on startup. Highly unlikely anyone ever made anything like that as a device addon.

Comment: Even in a modern CPU, saving all state takes a fair amount of hardware support within the core, so I'd agree with the assessment.